# How to programmatically press combination of keys at once in a UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, keyboard-events, keycode

I want to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> at the same time in C#.

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void keybd_event(uint bVk, uint bScan, uint dwFlags, uint dwExtraInfo);

public static void pressKey(KeyCode keycode)
{
    keybd_event(Convert.ToUInt16(keycode), 0, 0, 0);
}
```

This method will only press one key at a time.

Edit: This is not a windows form application, this is UWP app.

This is a UWP application so windows form methods most likely won't work here, please stop marking my question a similar question.

Comment: No, this is a UWP app so send keys method won't work here i think, since the method uses windows forms.

Comment: Does [How to Simulate a Tab Key Press with Code in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56636716/how-to-simulate-a-tab-key-press-with-code-in-uwp) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

> How to programmatically press combination of keys at once in a UWP app

You could refer [Keyboard accelerators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/keyboard-accelerators) document to make the keyboard accelerator, define the  keyboard accelerator for UWP control in the xaml

```
<Button Content="Save" Click="OnSave">
  <Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
    <KeyboardAccelerator Key="S" Modifiers="Control" />
  </Button.KeyboardAccelerators>
</Button>
```

Define in the code behind

```
private void TextBlock_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    var ctrlState = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().GetKeyState(Windows.System.VirtualKey.Control);
    var isCtrlDown = ctrlState == CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down || ctrlState 
        ==  (CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down | CoreVirtualKeyStates.Locked);
    if (isCtrlDown && e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.S)
    {
        // Your custom keyboard accelerator behavior.
        
        e.Handled = true;
    }
 }
```