# Programmatically add a wireless display on Windows using Miracast

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, uwp, miracast

I am looking to develop a WPF application, if not UWP app,  that will programmatically add a specific device (a Samsung Tablet) as a wireless display device for Win10. Eg. I have only 1 screen now, I want to add the tablet as my Screen 2 (extend my current Desktop).

It is basically what the 'Win key + K' does, minus the device selection part. Both the Win 10 system and the tablet will be on the same Wifi network.

I have checked out the following samples from Windows UWP samples.

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/BasicMediaCasting
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/AdvancedCasting
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/Projection

Using 'Win + K', or using 'add a wireless display' option from Display Settings I am able to find the tablet and connect to it, and enable UIBC, so that I can use the tablet stylus to work on tablet for Windows program such as Whiteboard.

With BasicMedia Casting and AdvanceCasting samples, I am either unable to find the tablet device, or find the device with a 'Phone' icon/category in front. (For 'Win +K' option, the tablet is showed as a 'display' category. ) And I am unable to connect to the tablet with the 2 samples.

With Projection sample, I am able to find and connect to the tablet, but no way to enable UIBC. In addition, Project sample projects a particular application to the tablet, not showing a desktop, although I find out that it does add the tablet as a 2nd screen.

May I know if there is any sample that is suitable for me?
Or can point me to any documentation on this topic?
And how to enable UIBC programmatically in Windows?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

> Programmatically add a wireless display on Windows using Miracast

I have to say, wireless display is system level, there no such api could manage it within UWP platform.  BasicMedia Casting is used to cast the **media** for SMTC, and the receive device need to support casting.

Projection sample shows how to display two different views of your app UI on different screens, as users might do when projecting your app in a meeting or conference.

Comment: Yes, I need to do system level projection and not App level. If there is no UWP API, is there any for WPF or even Win32 level APIs?

Comment: What feature that you want to implement? just add wireless display? why out use system setting page to add the display device ?

Comment: The main feature would be on the tablet itself.  But we want to create seamless experience for user to connect their Windows PC to the tablet and use the tablet as a second screen. So we have a companion App on Windows that triggers this 'second screen' feature, among other features.

Comment: Or is there any way to programmatically call out System setting page 'Win + P' and select 'extended' mode and select 'Add a wireless display' option and choose a particular device?

Comment: Yep, you could simulate keyboard input within uwp by using keyboard input injection. here is case [replay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56644752/7254781) that you could refer. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection.injectedinputkeyboardinfo?view=winrt-20348)is official document

Comment: Thanks @Nico. I am aware there are ways to programmatically send 'Win + K' or 'Win + P' to desktop. But is there any way to programmatically select the particular tablet named 'ABC' on the pop up side bar and tick the 'enable UIBC' checkbox?

Comment: As far as I know there is no such api in the uwp platform.